# How would a civilization on a planet with 1/10 Earth gravity look like?

Tags: science-based, medieval, gravity, microgravity

I have a lot of book ideas, and one of them is set on a planet with very low gravity. It has the same size as Earth, but with 1/10 the density. It has no satellites.

How would the lifeforms be different from the Earth's, and how would civilization have adapted compared to Earth (eg. buildings, agriculture/hunting, warfare)? Assume medieval-age technology if that matters.

Comment: Lifeforms would be enourmously different from Earth, or uncannily Earth like, depending on the story you want to tell. Civilization would have adapted splendidly, for example buildings would be just right for the given weight of materials; agriculture would be agricultural, unless the story wants to make agriculture magical, or industrial, or sublime, or ineffable, or something else; there would be no warfare, or there would be terrible warfare, or something in between, depending on the story you want to tell. And you may want to think more about what "medieval age technology" *means*.

Comment: If we want to keep it "science-based", we need to develop a solution to how this planet would hold to its atmosphere.

Comment: You guy are right, I guess. I voted to close my own question instead of outright deleting it, but I really can't find a way to ask this properly.